# How to make the images appear in a specific location?

Tags: 2d, android

How can I draw a sprite in a specific location of the screen using native Android 2D graphics API?

The image should stay in the location specified.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Answer**

Based on the Android API Reference on [Canvas.drawBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29), I came up with this:

```
   ...

   private Bitmap bmp=null;

   //Called once at startup
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(){
         //Load a bitmap from a resource (file in drawable folder in your project)
         bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_drawable);
   }

   //Called every time a redraw is required
   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         //Clear background to black
         canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
         //Draw bitmap
         float x=0.0f; //Distance from the left edge of the canvas
         float y=0.0f; //Distance from the top edge of the canvas
         //Draw
         canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x,y, null);
   }

   ...
```

For a better more comprehensive example, please look at [this](http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame4.html).